# AngularJS: Loading Page Outside of SPA Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a SPA app using ngRoute in AngularJS to load all the relevant views which is working great. My index.html houses all those various views and displays the constant headers and footers of the app. Now the designer wants to have two pages inside the app that don't conform to that template structure. They will have no header and footer and have a different background color.

So my question is, does anyone know of a good way to load pages outside of the routing format? When I try to navigate directly to the page I get the error:

Cannot GET /pageName.html

Comment: I would simply hide the header and footer using CSS. Apply some special class to the `<body>` element in your route controllers for those pages.

Comment: That's an interesting approach and should work.